# How to set a custom font in the button in the XML code? For example comic sans MS

Tags: xml, button, fonts, italic

I am a noob. I've seen some of the solutions here, and that just bounced above my head. Can anyone please help me setting up a font in the button? Also, if I can make it italic, bold etc. Here's my XML code

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:background="@drawable/crea"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use comic sans MS without purchasing a license:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-redistribution-licensing

There are free similar fonts available:

https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/comic-relief

Basic operation in using a different font is to add the font file to the **assets** folder in the project then use **setTypeface** on the widget:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "ComicRelief.ttf");
Button bt=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
bt.setTypeface(font);
```

Full info on using fonts here:

https://tekeye.uk/android/examples/android-textview-edittext-font

Comment: I added it in the asset folder. Also, added in the code. Here is how it looks.
        @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "TickingTimebombBB.ttf");
  TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  tv.setTypeface(font);

 }

But how do I use it later? When I go to the properties of the textview, I only see the default values. I also saved the code and checked, it still doesn't show up?